# Excluding JAR Files From the EAR using maven

Tags: maven, jar, package, ear, maven-ear-plugin

My EAR includes 8 JAR files which are in the **root** of my EAR. I want to delete two of them for my final deployment EAR package.

I was trying do this as it is described here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/excluding-files-from-ear.html

But seem not to work.

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
       <configuration>  
        <packagingExcludes>test1.jar,test2.jar</packagingExcludes>
      </configuration>
   ...
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Try with `<packagingExcludes>**/test1.jar,**/test2.jar</packagingExcludes>`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried many options inside these tags and none of the work.

Comment: What are the artifactId of the JAR you want to exclude? Because the name in the exclusion is based on the final name `{artifactId}-{version}.jar`

Comment: I haven't resolved issue using maven-ear-plugin. Instead of I was able to do it using maven-antrun-plugin.